# How to access to the value of a multi-nested DataFrame using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, nested

I have the following DataFrame schema:

```
root
 |-- event: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- idEvent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contract: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- idApplication: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- idVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- entity: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- idEntity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- entityType: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- entityNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- entityVersion: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- entityCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- idCode: string (nullable = true)
```

From this schema we get a DataFrame which consists of a single column: `event`.

I am looking to retrieve the `idCode` attribute located in the `entityVersion` array. Do you know if there is a way to retrieve the `idCode` value without having to flatten the whole DataFrame with methods like `explode`?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First to use to load json as `df` varibale
then you use `select` by like this code below

```
val df1 = df.select("event.version.entity.entityType.entityVersion.idCode")
df1.show()
```

no need to take whole data or `explode` the columns.